# What changes should I do in the function-like macro to make it MISRA compliant?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, misra

The function-like macro is

```
#define ARRAYSIZE(_Array)  ((sizeof(_Array)) / (sizeof(_Array[0])))
```

The error shown is:

> Error[Pm154]: in the definition of a function-like macro, each instance of a parameter shall be enclosed in parenthesis (MISRA C 2004 rule 19.10)

Answer (score 6):

It's just pedantically saying that you should be doing this `sizeof( (_Array)[0] )`. Postfix operators have very high precedence so it's unlikely to become an actual problem.

Pedantically you should also use `0u` since the intention is for the 0 to correspond to an unsigned type (`size_t`).

Also please note that leading underscore followed by upper-case letter is reserved for any use in the C language, MISRA or no MISRA.

I'd replace this whole macro with:

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE(array) ( sizeof(array) / sizeof *(array) )
```

Should be compliant both to the C language and MISRA-C.